# Why is Space 3D?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

Why is ***Space*** a ***THREE DIMENSIONAL ENTITY***?

I know that In physics and mathematics, the dimension of a mathematical space is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within it

I'm a **student** and I have tried to find the answer to this question but I probably didn't get any answer that I understand...

So pls help me with this as *I'm still a beginner here!*

P.S : There's a similar question at [Is 3+1 spacetime as privileged as is claimed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/)

but I kinda didn't get my answer there if there's anyone who can explain in a simpler manner request you to

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45495, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651

Comment: Actually, I didn't get the answer right there, it just went above my head!

Comment: It is an experimental fact. In Physics we use experimental (input) data in our models. In particular, in Geometry, the space dimensions is 3.

Comment: So anytime can we have more dimensions coming up?(in general space)

Comment: Why 3 dimensions? In large part, because that is all you can perceive. Various theories have space a 7, 11, even 21-dimensional. Are the other dimensions *actually* curled up into themselves, or do we just perceive it as such from our limited 3(+1)D viewpoint? These questions are hard to answer, and even harder to prove.