# References on how dimensionality relates to inverse square laws

Tags: newtonian-gravity, resource-recommendations, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions, coulombs-law

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Privileged_character_of_3.2B1_spacetime

[Does Coulomb's Law, with Gauss's Law, imply the existence of only three spatial dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451)

[Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/2451)

This wikipedia article claims that the existence of inverse square laws (like Newton's Law of Gravitation) has a connection with the fact that our universe has three large scale spatial dimensions.

Can someone point me to some book/paper where this topic is treated in a detailed and formal manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the divergence theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

It tells you that the flux of a vector field through a surface is equal to the integral over the divergence inside the Volume.

Since in 3 Dimensions Objects have surfaces scaling with $r^2$ and mass, charge etc. can be seen as positive divergence, or sources, of the corresponding force fields, we get inverse square laws. in Dimension d however surfaces scale with $r^{d-1}$ and we get $\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$ laws.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. In 3 dimensions when you transmit a wave uniformly in all directions the energy at any distance as it propagates is the same. Since the area of a sphere at distance r is $4\pi r^2$ the energy per unit area at any distance is inversely proportional to $r^2$. If the spatial dimensions were n it'd be inversely proportional to $r^{n-1}$