# Validity of Gauss Law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions, coulombs-law

> If the electric field due to a point charge varies as $r^{-2.5}$ instead of $r^{-2}$, then would the Gauss Law still be valid?

I infer that the $r^{-2}$ term in the Electric field comes as a result of solid angle in 3 dimensions. Would this be valid in higher dimensions? The flux would depend on the spatial dimensions. Because in the verification of Gauss law the $\frac{da}{r^2}$ terms is written as solid angle. Does this mean for Electric field varying in some other way, we would be talking about the solid angle of that dimension?

Even if it were true for higher dimensions, which it might be, does it hold for fractional powers of $r$?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic The fractional dimensions are not talked about in the referred link. Please open the question for answers.

Comment: The same argument carries over.