# What are the "derivations" of the inverse-square law?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, differential-geometry, gauss-law, geometry, coulombs-law

Besides the derivation mentioned in this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), I want to know, if there exists any other derivation of the inverse-square law based on some profound physical/philosophical concepts.

Comment: See [Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) for a potential that gives you an inverse square-law force.

Comment: The inverse square law for what?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @J.Murray Gravitation, for instance.

Comment: The inverse square law for gravitational force, electrostatic force, light intensity, etc is purely geometrical.  It is very easy to work out the areas involved for yourself.  Physics and philosophy have nothing to do with it.  Physics experiments only verify the inverse square laws.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an informal assumption, we could derive the inverse square law for gravitational force and Coulomb force.

## Assumption

Suppose everything in the space is scaled up by a factor of $k$, and time stays the same, then we shouldn't expect anything to change.

## Derivation

Since we are in a 3D space, any volume would be scaled by $k^3$, and so would mass.

From $F = ma$:

$$F' = (k^3m)(ka) = k^4ma = k^4F$$

Then suppose $F_G = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^n}$; after scaling up, $F_G' = G\frac{(k^3m_1)(k^3m_1)}{k^nr^n} = k^{6-n}F_G$; also, we know $F_G' = k^4F_G$, so $6-n = 4$, and $n = 2$.

Note: this piece of text is composed by one of my friends, Yushun Cheng.

Comment: Yes. However, the importance of scaling in physics has previously been introduced by me as the general observation principle (GOP): https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1536121053/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i0

Comment: You can also access my article here: https://scicom.ru/journals/ged/ged_vol28/ged_vol28_sissue3/ged_vol28_sissue3_02/