Why does gravity obey an inverse square law?
I am reading Martin Rees' Just Six Numbers, and came across this paragraph, where the author explains why a three-dimensional universe implies an inverse square law.

I understand the argument, but my intuition is still not fully satisfied. I accept the argument in the case of light radiating from a point source, for example.  In that case one can think of the rays of light or the photons as the "lines of force"; there is something physical that spreads around the spheres, and therefore becomes less dense. But what would that thing be in the case of gravity? Should I imagine "rays of gravity" in the same way I imagine rays of light?

In a way, yes. Another way of characterising such physics is that masses' gravitational effects are additive. It's basically the same story for the electrostatic force between charges.

"Why does gravity obey an inverse sqaure [sic] law?" We can not tell you "why" the world is the way it is.

@hft Martin Rees (and Michael Faraday, apparently) tried. I'm just trying to get to the bottom of their explanation.

@J.G. wouldn't using Gauss's law be circular reasoning here? The part that I'm trying to understand is why flux would be constant in the first place (this is what the "lines of force" argument tries to explain).

I'm just saying that it is an experimental fact that gravity (approximately) obeys an inverse square law. We can model this (approximate) behavior of (classical) gravity with certain equations, but we can not say why the facts of the world are what they are.

There is no circular reasoning because you can't reason physical laws into existence in the first place. You have to accept at least one physical statement to arrive at the inverse square law. Either you accept that gravity follows an inverse square law, or accept that it follows Gauss's law and derive the inverse square law. Or accept the Schwarzschild metric and derive the inverse square law as an approximation, etc. etc.

Furthermore, it is known that apparently inverse square law forces, e.g., electromagnetic forces, are only approximately inverse square laws, and quantum corrections change the force law.

(So any explanation regarding "why" the electric force is an inverse square law is "wrong" since the electric force actually is not an inverse square law... it is only an inverse square law under certain experimental conditions...)

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451 and links therein.


the author explains why a three-dimensional universe implies an inverse square law.

This explanation is an appeal to your intuition, but it does not explain "why" the electric (or gravitational) force is an inverse square law in three dimensions. For example, it does not explain "why" the electric force should depend on "how concentrated the lines of force are." It only asserts this and then indicates that if this is true then somehow the force must be an inverse square law.
We can say other things to explain how inverse square laws relate to the equations of motion for photons and gravitons and their sources, but ultimately physics is based on experiments and our explanation (our theoretical physics) needs to fall in line with the experimental results.
Suppose I told you that a photon was a massless particle, and that such a particle has a momentum-space propagator that looks like
$$
D(p) \sim \frac{1}{p^2}\;.
$$
And suppose that I further told you that I can figure out the force law by taking the derivative of the Fourier transform of the propagator like
$$
F(r) \sim \frac{d}{dr}\int d^3 p e^{-i\vec p\cdot \vec r} \frac{1}{p^2} \sim \frac{1}{r^2}\;.
$$
And suppose that I further told you that in $D$ dimensions the force should look like
$$
F_D(r) \sim \frac{d}{dr}\int d^D p e^{-i\vec p\cdot \vec r} \frac{1}{p^2} 
\sim \frac{1}{r^{D-1}}\tag{1}\;.
$$
Does this explain "why?" I don't think so. But it does link some notions of massless force carriers to the force laws and the dimensionality of space.

Further, it is a textbook problem to determine the fields due to a point charge, an infinite line of charge, and an infinite sheet of charge, in three dimensions, using Gauss's law. Such calculations end up providing the same results as Eq. (1), namely that the field due to a point charge falls off as $1/r^2$, the field due to the line charge falls off as $1/r$, and the field due to the sheet of charge is constant (on one side of the sheet).

The argument is wrong.  There are other fundamental forces (v.g. weak or strong force) that do not go like $1/r^2$, even if the 3d argument should apply to these just as they apply to gravity and the electrostatic force.
The $1/r^2$ dependence is particular in that the net flux of the E-field or the gravitational field depends only on the net source inside the volume enclosed by the surface through which the flux is computed, but it is not clear why this coincidence occurs for these but not for the other forces.

Putting aside what why means since that's been a sticky point on this page, I mentioned in a comment that one way of... looking at it, for want of a better unobjectionable term, is that some interactions are additive (at least in the domain of applicability of a $1/r$ potential). If we compare electromagnetism to the nuclear interactions, this is "because" the field equations are linear, which is "because" of certain Lie groups being Abelian. Linearized gravity exists in a certain regime.

@J.G. right but as you realize this simply displaces the question as to why some interactions should be additive while others should not, or alternatively because some gauge groups are Abelian and others note.  At any rate, none of this is tied to 3d.

Fine, "$r^{1-D}$ force in $D$ spatial dimensions" (so in $D=2$ the potential's logarithmic). But I think changing the question from e.g. "why that formula for electromagnetism?" to "why is the photon neutral & massless?" is more of an achievement than mere "displacement".

@J.G. if you are a high energy physicist certainly yes it is more of an achievement than a displacement.  I still think there is no satisfactory answer at this time, and that the answer in the OP is unsatisfactory.  Maybe there is an anthropic answer: anything else means no possibly of carbon-based life.  I certainly don’t have a convincing answer of my own.  (Additivity is a nice argument…)
