Does the force of gravity equation include only one dimension?
Been in a debate with someone who is claiming the force of gravity equation describes three dimensions. I was under the impression there is only one dimension relevant in the equation, that being the distance. Which view is correct?

Related: Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional? & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/123208

The force acts in all three dimensions, the magnitude is 1 d. but $\vec{F}=-G\frac{Mm}{||r||^3}\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}$ is 3d

I understand that  ⃗ is 3d, but does writing out the basic equation ⃗ =∗∗/2 suggest more than one dimension?

This is just the magnitude of the force, and I said all ready, that this is 1d.

@Bob516 $F = \frac {GMm}{r^2}$ only gives you the magnitude (size) of the gravitational force, so it is incomplete. The full 3D vector version is the one that trula gives in their answer.

@Bob516 All spatial vectors in a classical mechanics such as $\vec F, \vec a, \vec v, \vec s, \vec r $, etc are 3D by definition. Even surface normal is 3D, because surface can be oriented arbitrary in space and curved anyhow accordingly also. Basically if you have a vector in space, it's 3D because same is space. Note,- there may be vectors defined to operate in an arbitrary parameter sets $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \dots)$ which has nothing to do with spatial representation.

Gravitational force, like all forces, is a vector comprising a direction in 3 dimensions and a magnitude.  In some cases, the direction can be ignored, usually because in such a case the direction doesn't change, and the problem is effectively 1-dimensional.

In Newtonian gravity, the gravity depends on distance between two bodies depends on $r$, which is one dimension according to spherical coordinates. But in Euclidean system, it is three coordinates, $R^2 =x^2+y^2+z^2$, so gravity can be thought of as one or three according to your choice of coordinate system.

Even in spherical coordinates, $\vec{r}$ is 3d
